# Replace multiple spaces with semi-colon in a string in powerscript

Tags: string, replace, sybase, space, powerbuilder

Given a string like (2  5). I want to replace multiple spaces with a semi-colon in a string (2  5) in PowerBuilder

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with a regular expression. But the support for regular expression in Powerscript is minimal, you need to use an external COM object like `VBScript.RegExp` to do something useful.

```
OLEObject re
int li_retcode
string s
string value

re = Create OLEObject
li_retcode = re.ConnectToNewObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "\s\s+"
re.Global = True

s = "4  2"
value = re.Replace("4   2" , ";")

MessageBox("", value) // 4;2

re.DisconnectObject()
```

Answer (score 1):

simply cut out each word, **trim** and join into a string.

```
string   ls_key = '2  5  8 9'
string ls_new = ''
long ll_pos

do

  ll_pos = Pos( ls_key, ' ')

  if ll_pos > 0 then
    ls_new += trim( left( ls_key, ll_pos - 1) ) + ':'
    ls_key = trim( mid( ls_key, ll_pos + 1 ) )
  else
    ls_new += trim( ls_key )
    ls_key = ''
  end if  

loop while ll_pos > 0

return ls_new
```